# Concatenating strings using + operator

Tags: go

## Case 1

Below code is concatenating space characters with a label string

```
func printTree(t Tree, nSpaces int) {
    labelValue := strings.Repeat("  ", nSpaces) + string(label(t))
    fmt.Println(labelValue)
    for _, branch := range t.branches {
        printTree(branch, nSpaces+1)
    }
}
```

---

which prints invalid string, as shown below:

[image]

---

## Case 2

Below code:

```
func printTree(t Tree, nSpaces int) {
    labelValue := strings.Repeat("  ", nSpaces) + strconv.Itoa(label(t))
    fmt.Println(labelValue)
    for _, branch := range t.branches {
        printTree(branch, nSpaces+1)
    }
}
```

---

prints valid string.

```
3
  1
  2
    1
    1
```

---

`label()` returns integer as shown below:

```
func label(t Tree) int {
    return t.rootLabel
}
```

---

`go vet` does not give any clue

```
$ go vet Main.go
$ go version
go version go1.14.3 linux/amd64
$
```

---

Why Case 1 is failing with this syntax `strings.Repeat("  ", nSpaces) + string(label(t)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`string(i)` where `i` is a number does not return string representation of `i`. It returns a string containing one rune whose value  is `i`. If you run `go vet`, it will say:

> conversion from int to string yields a string of one rune, not a string of digits (did you mean fmt.Sprint(x)?)

Comment: Run it on go playground, and it should. I think they added this particular warning in 1.15.

Comment: Asuming this is Linux/amd64 OS, `string` data type is a header {pointer, length} which is 16 byte header, where *pointer* points to actual string and *length* has the lenght of the string. In `string(i)`, `i` is 8 byte memory, storing its value. So, I did not get you, when you say: *It returns a string containing one rune whose value is i*

Comment: string(65) is "A"

Comment: How `string(65) ` different from `string(f())` ? where `f()` returns int with value 65..... Do you mean Rune literals are just 4 byte integer value, where as `int` is 8 byte?

Comment: It is not, and that's my point. With string(label(t)) in your example, you'll always get a string containing one rune. That is, string(label(t)) is equivalent to string([]rune{label(t)})

Comment: ok, so string() is taking that integer as UTF encoded value and showing the corresponding character in UTF-8 space. For example, if `label(t)` returns 66 then `string(label(t))` is B

Comment: Yes. A rune is a utf-8 encoded charater value, and an alias for int32